# MFCCs and chord recognition

Tags: mfcc, pitch

This is my first time working with Mel-frequency cepstral coefficients and I have two questions....

1. Are some of the 13 coefficients strictly related to some sound properties like frequencies, amplitude, pitch or something ? For example if I'm interested only in sound pitch, are there some coefficients that carry that information and I can exclude the rest of the coefficients that carry other information to reduce the size of the vector ? Or those coefficients means nothing individually and they must be used all together as a whole ?
2. I'm trying to learn Chord recognition methods. I was thinking for calculating MFCC from a short Wave file where chord is played. (It is just a chord played on piano, there is no ambient noise or other instruments). And after I get the 13 MFCCs, cluster them to a centroid which describes the appropriate chord. (24 centroids, 12 for minor chords, 12 for major). I'm just wondering, are the MFCCs good descriptor for the present pitches in the sound ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFCC's are related strictly to spectrum shape and what's more - these are relaying on the mel scale. Additionally each coefficient is a DCT value from fitted cosinusoids to log-energies. Thus interpretation of pitch would be troublesome for you.

Chord recognition is usually based on chromagram calculation or so called chroma features. Check out work and publications of guys from [QMUL](http://c4dm.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/), i.e: [Real-time Chord Recognition for live performance](http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~markp/2009/StarkPlumbley09-icmc.pdf) - in here you will find another references.

You might also find their software useful: [Sonic Visualizer](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/) together with lot's of so called [Vamp plugins](http://www.vamp-plugins.org/). You can check out the code and even use command line tool to extract features you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.... Does this mean that I can use MFCC for musical instrument recognition (if it is a trumpet, organ or violin for example) ?

Comment: @Alexander: Indeed you can use MFCC's for that purpose as a most simplistic approach. Also please keep in mind that you might want to use the same tones for achieving of the best performance.